# How to load json data into the id="hello"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>doers.lk</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p id="hello"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
  alert('Latitude: ' + data.latitude +
        '\n Longitude: ' + data.longitude +
        '\n Country: ' + data.address.country);
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NEWAC/)

I want to load this json data to the id="hello".What is the better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provide the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method that let you get/set the content of an element. In your callback you could select the element on its id and use the `.html()` method to add your content.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
  $("#hello").html('Latitude: ' + data.latitude +
        '<br /> Longitude: ' + data.longitude +
        '<br /> Country: ' + data.address.country);
});​
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEWAC/2/)

Comment: <script>
$("#success").load("/id.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
var d = new Date();
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=d.toLocaleDateString();
  </script>

Comment: I'm using ajax to load id.html.(id.html ) is contain my above html and json cords but now it's not working for this two methods

Comment: @KayleeMackenzie That is probably the topic of a new question then, so I suggest that you ask a new question where you describe your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
  $("#hello").html('Latitude: ' + data.latitude +
        '\n Longitude: ' + data.longitude +
        '\n Country: ' + data.address.country);
});​
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d4hGj/1/

Comment: you'd better use the native jquery methods `$(...).html()`, it's more clear to not mix native js and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/4mry4/)

jquery code

```
$.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/?callback=?', function (data) {
    $("#hello").html('Latitude: ' + data.latitude +
        '<br /> Longitude: ' + data.longitude +
        '<br /> Country: ' + data.countryName);
});
```

html

use smart-ip.net better than wipmania.com